How to request Data from Fragment to Activity? request Data with a button click in main activity?
I want to get Data to main activity from the fragment, my data is in the fragment, and when I click a button on the main activity, I need to grab that data within the main activity
I found a solution from StackOverflow, and here it is.
public void getFromUser(View view) {        
    ConversationFragment fragment1 = (ConversationFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    View frag=fragment1.getView();
    EditText editText1 =(EditText) frag.findViewById(R.id.message);
    String message=editText1.getText().toString();
    sendMessage(message);

}
but few people have mentioned that it is a bad practice, then I heard of doing something like that with an interface, I am new to Java, so can someone mention a sample of getting data to the main activity from a fragment with a button click on a main activity

Does this answer your question? Passing Data Between Fragments to Activity

hi @Maveňツ I want to do the other way around, capture the data from fragment with a button click in hosting activity, in activity I see onAttachFragment method, can I proceed with that?

Your question is not clear, can you elaborate your UI where button is placed where data needs to be sent in the question itself by editing it?

@Maveňツ my Button is placed on main activity, and my EditText is in the Fragment, problem is I don't have any event in the fragment, only the edit text, in that case I need to get that EditText value when user press the button which is placed on the MainActivity

Use a ViewModel for this: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate
then you can observe changes for the data and do whatever you want with it.

In my case i don't have any Event to trigger within the Fragment, it contains only the EditText, so I want to grab that value when user press the Button which is placed in the MainActivity
